# Example of strictfp sensitive JVM

Tags: java

We all pretty much know how **strictfp** works.

Something like this:

```
package com.hk.basicjava.tests.strictfp;

import java.util.*;

public class StrictFP {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        double d = Double.MIN_VALUE; 
        System.out.println("non strictfp : " + notStrictFP(d)); // may be 4.9E-324
        System.out.println("strictfp : " + strictFP(d)); // should be 0
    }

    static double notStrictFP(double a) {
        return (a / 2 ) * 2;
    }
    static strictfp double strictFP(double a) {
        return (a / 2 ) * 2 ;
    }
}
```

But, does any one know **particular hardware/OS** (and maybe JRE) **combination** where there is a difference in results returned by methods with and without **strictfp** specifiers?

I tried several combinations, but there was no difference.

Comment: Is a *practical problem* for you then, if you can't find one that makes a difference? :-)

Comment: @GregKopff It may become a practical problem. You'd better know in advance when it may become a practical problem.

Comment: @GregKopff If someone's writing a set of in-house coding practices it could be helpful to know if this is still relevant.

Comment: I don't know which formulas would best test such round-off, but I'm pretty sure the values should not be optimizable by the runtime.  For example, I'd do `a / x` where x is defined as `static final double x = Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("nonexistentProperty", "2"));`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562510/does-java-strictfp-modifier-have-any-effect-on-modern-cpus

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a number that the double can represent accurately: Double.MIN_VALUE; so it doesn't surprise me that there's no difference. If you use arithmetic that produces a number that cannot retain its precision, the same arithmetic can produce two different results. strictfp would work in this case, where JVM approximates the answer the same way both times.