# Extended-exponent Value Sets in Java

Tags: java, jvm, jls

According to section 4.2.3 of JLS, particular Java implementation may support

1) float extended-exponent value set

2) double-extended-exponent value set

But this is not required.

**Example:**

If we have a product `2.3 * 3.7` and this product is located in non-strictfp context (i.e. in non-strictfp method or class) then before actual calculation of the product JVM has an option to choose between two Value Sets: `double value set` and `double-extended-exponent value set`.

Do you know particular Java implementation that support this feature?

Maybe this feature is supported in particular platform (Windows, Unix ,...)?

Comment: Seems that you mean not JSL, but JLS, right?

Comment: Probably related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22562510/4856258

Comment: Take a look on "strictfp" keyword. I used it long time ago, but I suppose that it can be useful.