# Does code becomes non - compliant in someway if strictfp not used?

Tags: java, portability, strictfp

We have a first code audit coming up and I was told by someone that not using `strictfp` for floating point arithmetic might get us flagged. Software is coded on Windows machine and deployed to Solaris machines for production use. Any suggestions about it being true?

Also, if not using 'strictfp`can make floating point arithmetic code non - compliant or non - portable, why is doing computation in **non - strictfp** way allowed anyway?

[CERT Secure Coding Standards, NUM53-J](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM53-J.+Use+the+strictfp+modifier+for+floating-point+calculation+consistency+across+platforms) makes me feel like it's mandatory to use `strictfp`:

> Programs that require consistent results from floating-point operations across different JVMs and platforms must use the strictfp modifier.

Comment: Don't just link, also quote the relevant bit. I've guessed at the bit you probably meant.

Comment: If you're deploying it to Windows or Solaris on Intel hardware then it makes no difference whether you have strictfp or not. (But if there is any chance that you deploy to hardware for which strictfp does make a difference, then it's a good idea to have strictfp all over your code) See answers to one of my older questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562510/does-java-strictfp-modifier-have-any-effect-on-modern-cpus

Comment: When you say "non-compliant" - non-compliant with what?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - for portability.

Comment: @Erwin - Thanks, thats very helpful. Developer machines are Intel ones, trying to find production server details.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan: Yes, but production server details can change over time, as can developer machine details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for pointing root of problem and usage of BigDecimal  or similar techniques. There are places in code ( old pieces ) where integer + scale way is not being followed but pure float and doubles. We need to correct that.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan: Good deal, glad to have helped. Good luck with the audit (not that it sounds like you need luck)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your application needs floating-point operations to be consistent between different JVMs, then yes, you need `strictfp`. If it *doesn't*, then no, you don't. Some applications don't need consistency and benefit from the potential for greater precision during intermediate steps of calculations that not using `strictfp` can offer. Others need to give exactly the same output for the same inputs, and thus require `strictfp` to guarantee that output portably.

Comment: In my application, consistency ( same end result everywhere ) matters as product deals with mortgage interest rate and stuff like that. I am guessing that we need strictfp.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan: If you're dealing with mortgage interest rates and other financial calculations, surely `strictfp` is irrelevant to your application, as it [only applies to `double` and `float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.3). You're not using `double`s or `float`s for financial calculations, are you? If so, you have a much bigger audit note coming. For financials, usually you want `BigDecimal` (or a direct implementaton of its technique, which is to use an integer value and a scale).